# Comparing files in directories

Tags: vba

In the code below I am trying to compare a Word document in the first  (`old`) folder with its revised version in the second (`new`) folder and saving the compared document in third (`result`) folder. The code is running perfectly fine and now compiles and with no run time errors.

But, after running it, only one compared file is being saved to the third folder i.e., even though I have three files in each folder, only the first file from each folder is being compared and being saved in the third folder. Also the saved file in the third (`result`) folder is not being opened, while stating that there is some problem with that file.

Any suggestions or ideas how can I resolve this?

---

```
Sub CompareAllFiles()
    Dim strFolderA As String
    Dim strFolderB As String
    Dim strFolderC As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objDocA As Word.Document
    Dim objDocB As Word.Document
    Dim objDocC As Word.Document
    strFolderA = "C:\Users\Rock\Desktop\old\"
    strFolderB = "C:\Users\Rock\Desktop\new\"
    strFolderC = "C:\Users\Rock\Desktop\result\"
    strFileSpec = "*.docx"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderA & strFileSpec)
    Do While strFileName <> vbNullString
        Set objDocA = Documents.Open(strFolderA & strFileName)
        Set objDocB = Documents.Open(strFolderB & strFileName)
        Application.CompareDocuments _
            OriginalDocument:=objDocA, _
            RevisedDocument:=objDocB, _
            Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew
        objDocA.Close
        objDocB.Close
        Set objDocC = ActiveDocument
        objDocC.SaveAs FileName:=strFolderC & strFileName
        objDocC.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
    Set objDocA = Nothing
    Set objDocB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in your code strikes me as "this can't possibly be working". However I do have suggestions for making your code easier to debug/maintain.

---

The ABC naming is utterly annoying and makes the code hard to follow - I find myself constantly referring back to the lines they're being assigned to remember what they stand for. Naming is hard, but it's worth it. Also consider declaring variables closer to their first usage/assignment, so reading the code goes smoothly from top to bottom:

```
Dim pathOld As String
pathOld = "C:\Users\Rock\Desktop\old\"

Dim pathNew As String
pathNew = "C:\Users\Rock\Desktop\new\"

Dim pathResult As String
pathResult = "C:\Users\Rock\Desktop\result\"
```

Consider making them constants, and/or using `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` instead of hard-coding a specific user.

Ditto with the document objects:

```
Dim docOld As Word.Document
Dim docNew As Word.Document
Dim docResult As Word.Document
```

What you're calling "file spec" is actually a "file filter" made up of a wildcard and a file extension.

```
Const fileExtension As String = ".docx"
Const fileFilter As String = "*" & fileExtension
```

Notice I'm also using Hungarian Notation - I'm using Hungarian Notation *the way it was intended to be used all along*, to describe the *kind* of variables I'm looking at (as opposed to the *data type* of variables, which is useless noise when you have the declaration right there in your face). "path" variables all describe a *path*, and "doc" variables all refer to a *document* object. Read [this excellent article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) for all the details on *making wrong code look wrong*.

You could actually get rid of the `result` document object altogether, by extracting some of that loop's body into its own function, and using a `With` block:

```
Dim currentFileName As String
currentFileName = Dir(pathOld & fileFilter)

Do While currentFileName <> vbNullString
    Set docOld = Application.Documents.Open(pathOld & currentFileName)
    Set docNew = Application.Documents.Open(pathNew & currentFileName)
    With CompareDocuments(docOld, docNew)
        .SaveAs FileName:=pathResult & currentFileName
        .Close
    End With
    currentFileName = Dir
Loop
```

I could be wrong (VBA object lifetime management has its quirks), but the last two `Set` statements don't appear to be useful at all.. I'd remove them.

---

```
Private Function CompareDocuments(ByVal docOld As Word.Document, ByVal docNew As Word.Document) As Word.Document
    'if we're given null references, break here and debug:
    Debug.Assert docOld Is Not Nothing And docNew Is Not Nothing

    Application.CompareDocuments _
        OriginalDocument:=docOld, _
        RevisedDocument:=docNew, _
        Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew
    docOld.Close
    docNew.Close

    'if there's no active document, something has gone wrong. break and debug:
    Debug.Assert Application.ActiveDocument Is Not Nothing
    Set CompareDocuments = Application.ActiveDocument
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link below.  I think this will do what you want, or at least, it will get you very close to where you need to be.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

[image]